# What's the difference between Evaluate and Replace command?

Tags: evaluation, replacement

all, I'm new to Mathematica, I am very confused between Evaluate and Replace (`/.`) command. I feel they are very similar.

For example,

```
In[2]:= y = x + 2;

y /. {x -> 3}

Out[3]= 5
```

However, if I use

```
In[1]:= y = x + 2;

Evaluate[y, x = 3]

Out[2]= Sequence[5, 3]
```

For both cases, I can get `y=5`.
I think for the convenience, we can always use `Replace` instead of `Evaluate` for the simple substitution, correct? Or is there any case I should use `Evaluate` only instead of using `Replace` if I want to substitute a symbol to another symbol or value?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use `Evaluate`.  It is for forcing evaluation of arguments to functions that have a `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, etc attribute, to force them to be evaluated before the value is passed to the function. -- `ReplaceAll` is fine, unless you want `x` to have the value `3` at the end. In that case `CompoundExpression` might be used (it's entered as a semi-colon): `x = 3; y`.  Note that in none of these does the value of `y` change; it is still defined as `x + 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to MMA SE (and MMA in general)!

#### Evaluate

So, the `Evaluate` command doesn't actually do anything similar to what you think it does, I think. It's actually only used for control flow, e.g. when you want to force an expression to evaluate where it wouldn't normally—these cases are uncommon, at least relative to everyday use.

Notice that `Evaluate[y, x = 3]` produces a `Sequence` object. This is a very unusual occurrence, and is due to the unusual use of `Evaluate`. A `Sequence` expression is generally not seen explicitly in code—only implicitly, e.g. via `f[1, 2, 3]`; `f` can be thought of as being fed `Sequence[1, 2, 3]` behind the scenes, to an extent. `Evaluate` typically takes 1 argument, and simply, well, evaluates it. Here, that argument is the `Sequence` `y, x = 3`, so that's what it returns.

The reason you see `5` in the second expression is because you've also evaluated `x = 3`. So, for example, try clearing `x` and evaluating `Sequence[y, x = 3]` directly; you'll get `Sequence[5, 3]`. `Evaluate` isn't really doing anything here.

What *is* doing the substitution is the variable assignment `x = 3`. This causes `x` to always evaluate to `3`. Mathematica evaluates expressions until they stop changing or are forced to return, so for example, consider the following:

```
Clear[x, y];
y = 2 + x;
x = 3;
TracePrint[y]
```

`TracePrint[y]` will show you the evaluation process of the expression `y`, with small indents each time Mathematica starts analyzing a subexpression. You can see `y` first gets evaluated to `2 + x`, and then when `x` is encountered, it gets evaluated to *its* definition, `3`. So the workhorse here is the definition `=`, not `Evaluate`.

**Note:** The terminology "evaluate an expression" is used to refer to whenever you hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, or, more generally, whenever the Mathematica kernel is processing an expression. This is to be distinguished from the actual function `Evaluate` that Mathematica provides, which is only slightly related!

#### ReplaceAll

In contrast to `Evaluate`, `ReplaceAll` is super versatile and used all the time! `ReplaceAll` relies on pattern-matching. If you're new to MMA, I'd recommend learning how to define functions with `:=` and a bit on pattern-matching in general; patterns are very useful in MMA. In the case of

```
Clear[x, y]
y = 2 + x;
y /. {x -> 3}
```

`y` is evaluated, then the literal pattern `x` (i.e., literally the symbol `x` itself) is looked for in the result, and then any `x`s that are found are replaced with whatever `3` has evaluated to (in this case, that's just `3`). Then the resulting expression continues being evaluated (`2 + 3` becomes `5`). The `TracePrint[y /. {x -> 3}]` output is a bit more confusing, but you can see Mathematica checking the `List` of `Rule`s `{x -> 3}` against each part of the expression if you want to check it. (This is the `All` in `ReplaceAll` (`/.`), by the way; `Replace` only checks the whole expression at once, not each part. Since the whole expression is not the symbol `x`, `Replace` would have no effect here.)

Note, by the way, that the `ReplaceAll` change is not persistent. Evaluate `y` again after `y /. {x -> 3}` and it will still be `2 + x`. In general, the only persistent changes in Mathematica are made by `=` and `:=` (plus a couple other related ones, like `/:` and `^:=`). The distinction between `=` and `:=` is important, and worth looking into: it has to do with when the right-hand-sides are evaluated. (in the case of `=`, the right hand side is evaluated first, then the definition is made; in the case of `:=`, the right hand side is made to be the definition of the left hand side verbatim, and is evaluated anew in each instance it's used. See the docs for more info here; there are some useful tutorials and guides!) All the rest of the operations you could perform only deal with the expression being evaluated in that very moment.

Hope this helps, and good luck! Let me know if you have any questions or if anything here was unclear.